# Calculate Average for Sequence of Strings, Remove anything 1SD or greater, then REPLACE value that is removed with the Mean

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

**I have a large dataset of over 10,000 rows: df:**

```
  User              duration

  amy                582         
  amy                27
  amy                592
  amy                16
  amy                250
  tom                33
  tom                10
  tom                40
  tom                100
```

**Desired output:**

```
User              duration

  amy                293.4         
  amy                27
  amy                293.4
  amy                16
  amy                250
  tom                33
  tom                10
  tom                40
  tom                45.75
```

We see here that any values greater than 1SD of the mean for the distinct user group was removed and then replaced with the mean (of the unique User name).
The mean for group amy is  293.4
The mean for group tom is: 45.75

**dput:**

```
structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("amy", "tom"), class = "factor"), duration = c(582L, 
27L, 592L, 16L, 250L, 33L, 10L, 40L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

This is what I have tried as suggested by one of the members here and this works fantastic, I am unsure how to actually now REPLACE the removed values with the mean for each group:

```
 df %>% 
 group_by(User) %>%
 filter(between(duration, mean(duration) -  1 * sd(duration), 
 mean(duration) +  1 * sd(duration)))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(User) %>%
    mutate(duration = replace(duration,
        !between(duration, mean(duration) -  1 * sd(duration), 
                 mean(duration) +  1 * sd(duration)), mean(duration)))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   User [2]
#  User  duration
#  <fct>    <dbl>
#1 amy      293. 
#2 amy       27  
#3 amy      293. 
#4 amy       16  
#5 amy      250  
#6 tom       33  
#7 tom       10  
#8 tom       40  
#9 tom       45.8
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
f1 <- function(x) as.numeric(abs(scale(x)) > 1)
with(df, ifelse(f1(duration), ave(duration, User), duration))
```